# How to trigger all of elements' onclick created in loop?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code:

```js
   var board = document.getElementById("left");
    for (var m = 0; m < 5; m++) {
        var cell = document.createElement('div');
        cell.className = "Cell";
        cell.style.cssText='background-color:#999999;margin:5px;width:50px;height:100px;';
        cell.onclick= function() {
                    cell.innerHTML = "Hello World";
            };
        cell.name = m;
        board.appendChild(cell);
    }
```

```html
    <div id="left"></div>
```

However, when I click every `div`, "Hello World" always show on the last `div`.
How can fix it?

Answer (score 4):

As value of `cell` is being assigned in the `loop`, it will hold the value of last `element`

Simple solution:

Use `this` in handler function! In `Event-handler` function, `this` refers to `element` on which event is invoked!

```js
var board = document.getElementById("left");
for (var m = 0; m < 5; m++) {
  var cell = document.createElement('div');
  cell.className = "Cell";
  cell.style.cssText = 'background-color:#999999;margin:5px;width:50px;height:100px;';
  cell.onclick = function() {
    this.innerHTML = "Hello World";
  };
  cell.name = m;
  board.appendChild(cell);
}
```

```html
<div id="left"></div>
```

**Or:** Use `closure`, `returned-function` remembers the environment in which it is created!

```js
var board = document.getElementById("left");
for (var m = 0; m < 5; m++) {
  var cell = document.createElement('div');
  cell.className = "Cell";
  cell.style.cssText = 'background-color:#999999;margin:5px;width:50px;height:100px;';
  cell.onclick = (function(cell) {
    return function() {
      cell.innerHTML = "Hello World";
    }
  })(cell);
  cell.name = m;
  board.appendChild(cell);
}
```

```html
<div id="left"></div>
```

Comment: The first solution gets the work done, second solution triggers curiosity :)

Comment: @sabithpocker — Search for it... Understand it... It is [_cool_ thing...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: Thank you, however, i tried put some functions into
cell.onclick = function() {
  }; but fail..

Comment: @Rayon I do understand that. Just appreciating your answering :)